# Showing $S^1$ is not a retract of $\mathbb{D}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, solution-verification, retraction

I am trying to show that $\mathbb{D}^2$ doesn't retract to $S^1$. I am using the fact that if $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ then if there is a retract $r:X\rightarrow{Y}$ with $r\circ{i}=Id_{X}$, with $i$ being an inclusion, then $i_*:H_n(X)\rightarrow{H_n(Y)}$ is injective.

Since we have

(i) $H_n(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$

(ii) $H_n(\mathbb{D}^2)=0$

clearly there is no such injection. But how do I show (i) and (ii)?

apologies if this is obvious.

note: im not looking for an alternative proof, just one that involves (i),(ii)

Comment: You mean $H_1(S^1)\cong \Bbb Z$? What homology are you working with?

Comment: In (i), (ii) you mean $H_1$, not $H_n$.

Comment: Yes I mean congruent and I mean singular homology and yes for the case n=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have $n=1$ for (i) to hold, but of course that's enough.

Proving it sort of depends on what you already know.

For (i) :

- If you know the Hurewicz theorem and that $\pi_1(S^1,1) = \mathbb Z$, then you are done
- If you know about cellular/simplicial homology, then you can easily compute $H_1(S^1)$ via the celullar/simplicial complex associated to the following decomposition : one $0$-cell, and one $1$-cell.
- If you know about the Mayer-Vietoris exact sequence, you can use it by choosing the opens to be two open intervals that cover $S^1$, e.g. $S^1$ minus the south pole and $S^1$ minus the north pole. Then you are reduced to knowing the homology of an interval. For this you can use any of the above $2$ methods, or the first method for $\mathbb D^2$ described below.

For (ii) :

- If you know that homology is homotopy invariant, you can notice that $\mathbb D^2$ is contractible, i.e. homotopy equivalent to a point, hence they have the same homology, and then the homology of a point is easy to compute.
- You can use any of the first two methods described for (i) above, if you know about them.